# Techniques to optimise the integral of a function of known analytical form

Tags: numerics, integration

I need to compute repeatedly a function that depends on an integral. The integral is not solvable analytically, but it depends on the argument of the function parametrically, like this:

$$
f(x) = \int_0^1g(x, u)du
$$

The function $g(x,u)$ is of known and fixed analytical shape, infinitely differentiable. My question is, is there any specialised algorithm that I can use to optimise this integral as much as possible, exploiting what I know of the function? I tried to see if it could be expressed as a Chebyshev series but no luck.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "optimising this integral"?

Comment: What do you know about the dependence of $g$ on $x$? Could you do a Taylor expension of $f$ around some $x$ by doing a Taylor expansion of $g$ around some $x$ for every $u$?

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate $f(x)$ with respect to $x$?  Could you differentiate $g(x,u)$ with respect to $x$ inside the integral?

Comment: @smh I want to make it as fast as possible to compute exploiting the fact that I know the integrand. Basically, I'd like a specialised algorithm rather than a general-purpose one like your typical quadrature.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth everything, I know the exact function, though it's rather complicated to write. But I'm not sure a Taylor expansion is any good as I need to cover a large range of $x$. I can expand in $u$ and thus define the integral as a sum of polynomial integrals on each small $du$, though. That's my first idea.

Comment: @BrianBorchers no, I don't need to differentiate $f$. I am wondering if there are good methods to exploit the derivatives of $g$, but mainly in $u$. I have no use for the ones in $x$.

Comment: So you're not trying to maximize or minimize $f(x)$?  What do you mean by "optimise"?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, I think that the OP refers to optimize the evaluation time of the integral.

Comment: If not a Taylor expansion, could you do a Fourier expansion of $f(x)$ for the range of $x$ values you consider? In the best of cases, that would only require a few evaluations of the integral.

Comment: As for the Taylor expansion, the question is not how different the $x$ values are for which you need the integral, but how fast the integral varies with $x$ and how large the nonlinearities (non-quadraticities, ...) are.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth the integral's kernel dependence on $x$ is exponential, and I don't have any prior knowledge of the range of $x$, though I could in theory define limit cases (I know for example that very big x will pretty much make it 0, and very small will make it a constant). That is an option, though I don't much like the idea of making this a discontinuous piece-wise function by adding edge cases.

The Fourier series idea though is interesting. I'll play around with it.